# Help hooking into user_register

Tags: php, hooks, users, user-registration, wp-create-user

I'm trying to do a POST request to my API when a user is created. 
I've installed Code snippets and added the following:

```
add_action('user_register','my_function');

function my_function($user_id){
    echo("Code has been run.");
    echo("<script>console.log('test')");
}
```

Now, when I register a new user, nothing is echoed.
The snippet is set to "Run snippet everywhere".

I hope I've been specific enough.

Comment: Is user created in admin panel or via register form? After successful addition of the user through the registration form, the redirection takes place. Look at the [example in codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_new_user). It's not a hook where you can `echo` anything.

Comment: For debugging purposes, before the end of the `my_function()` you can add `die();`. Then you will see the messages you are trying to display, but in the production code you can not display anything here.